# Keyword given with "Run Keyword if" doesnt get executed

Tags: robotframework

Below line is a part of a larger test case. it works up to this point. The line(Run Keyword If)  shows as passed in the log and the overall test case passes. However i know that this line is not executed because the "Log To Console" &  "Go Back Home" which is called in "Verify Message" is not executed.I also know that the condition ${TEST_TAGS} == "Positive1"  passes because i am printing the value of ${TEST_TAGS} just before calling "Run Keyword If". Please guide with any reasons why the "Verify Message" is not getting called & executed

```
      *** Test Cases ***` 
      ...
      ...
      Log To Console  ${TEST_TAGS}
      Run Keyword If  ${TEST_TAGS} == "Positive1"  Verify Message  ${Final message}  ${TEST_TAGS} 

     *** Keywords ***
     Verify Message
     [Arguments]         ${Final message}  ${TEST_TAGS} 
     Log To Console  ${TEST_TAGS}  
     Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${Final message}  timeout=50
     Go Back Home

     Go Back Home
     Click Element  xpath://div[@class="button contribute primary"]
     Title Should Be        ${Title}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're missing quotes arount `${TEST_TAGS}` like it says so in the documentation: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If

```
Run Keyword If  '${TEST_TAGS}'=='Positive1'
```

And `${TEST_TAGS}` should be a string, not e.g. an array which the name suggests.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after adding the quotes and doing a string comparison.Earlier i was comparing array to a string                                                                                        Run Keyword If  '${TEST_TAGS}[0]' == 'Positive1'  Verify Message  ${Final message}  '${TEST_TAGS}[0]'